# Generate a new column or matrix with a length based on the values in one column and the actual values of another column

Tags: r

Say you have two numeric columns like this:

```
1 5
2 4
3 2
4 1
5 8
```

The length (i.e, number of rows) and values of both columns can vary, but both will always be the same length (i.e., each column will have a corresponding value).

I'd like to create a function that will eliminate the two columns and/or replace them with one of [n,1] length. The number of rows will be determined based on the values in column 2, but the actual populated values will be the corresponding values from column 1. For example, using the example above, there would be a single column that begins with 5 rows of 1, 4 rows of 2, 2 rows of 3 and so on. It would be something like this.

```
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
3
3
4
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
```

I'm not sure if something like `nrow()` or `ncol()` would be useful in this case, because it's not the length of the matrix itself that matters, but rather the actual values that determine the length. I've tried using rep() with seq() to no avail, but I'm also not sure if I would need something like `array()` or `vector()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`uncount()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/uncount.html):

```
tidyr::uncount(df, V2)
```

Output:

```
   V1
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   1
6   2
7   2
8   2
9   2
10  3
11  3
12  4
13  5
14  5
15  5
16  5
17  5
18  5
19  5
20  5
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text="
1 5
2 4
3 2
4 1
5 8"
)
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. I had no idea `uncount()` even existed

Answer (score 2):

You could use `rep` to create your desired vector like so:

```r
rep(1:5, c(5, 4, 2, 1, 8))
#>  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

Comment: how would you do this if the values were in numeric columns, as opposed to straight vectors? :-)

Comment: @Mark `with(df, rep(V1, V2))`